# Repeated problems when using "split"

Tags: equations

I have tried to use the methods learned here, but I get misalign as usual with split:

```
   \begin{equation}
\begin{split}
           \beta_k=\frac{1}{L}\int_{-3}^{2}f(t)\sin\frac{2k\pi}{5}t\text{d}t=\frac{4}{5}\int_{-3}^{-1.5}\sin\frac{2k\pi}{5}t\text{d}t+\frac{2}{5}\int_{-1.5}^{0.2}\sin\frac{2k\pi}{5}t\text{d}t+\\&\frac{4}{5}\int_{0.2}^{1}\sin\frac{2k\pi}{5}t\text{d}t+\frac{6}{5}\int_{1}^{2}\sin\frac{2k\pi}{5}t\text{d}t\longrightarrow\\&
           \beta_k=\frac{1}{k}\bigg(0.254648 \cos \left(\frac{\pi  k}{2}\right)+0.509296 \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi  k}{2}\right)\\&-0.254648 \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi  k}{4}\right)+0.254648 \cos \left(\frac{\pi  k}{10}\right)-0.763944 \cos (\pi  k)\bigg)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Any ideas what can be done to align this to the left?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
     \beta_k=\;&\frac{1}{L}\int_{-3}^{2}f(t)\sin\frac{2k\pi}{5}t\text{d}t=\frac{4}{5}\int_{-3}^{-1.5}\sin\frac{2k\pi}{5}t\text{d}t+\frac{2}{5}\int_{-1.5}^{0.2}\sin\frac{2k\pi}{5}t\text{d}t+{}\\
     &\frac{4}{5}\int_{0.2}^{1}\sin\frac{2k\pi}{5}t\text{d}t+\frac{6}{5}\int_{1}^{2}\sin\frac{2k\pi}{5}t\text{d}t\longrightarrow\\
     \beta_k=\;&\frac{1}{k}\bigg(0.254648 \cos \left(\frac{\pi  k}{2}\right)+0.509296 \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi  k}{2}\right)-{}\\
     &0.254648 \cos \left(\frac{3\pi k}{4}\right)+0.254648 \cos \left(\frac{\pi  k}{10}\right)-0.763944 \cos (\pi  k)\bigg)
    \end{split}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Maybe the line-breaking position needs to be reconsidered since you have two `=` in the first line. Essentially, you align at the `&`, so you can adjust the position.

Note the empty bracket at `+{}\\`, which ensures appropriate space before the + symbol.
If you want the operator at the begin of the line, you need `&{}+` as well.

Comment: U.S. publishers usually expect that a binary operator (plus or minus) be placed at the beginning of the continuation line, shifted somewhat right from the =.